# Android kernel LED control

Tags: button, kernel, led

Im new to this forum so be nice ;) i have followed rules :)

I am helping the dev for my kernel that I use. Since the mod I want is mainly only for me i figured its my duty to get it working myself.

The problem:
I have edited my *.kl files to disable the five front facing hardware buttons from waking the device and only allow the volume up / down buttons to wake the device as the front facing buttons get pressed when its in my pocket.

However, even though the front facing buttons no longer turn on the device , when they get pressed they light up adding an extra 6mA drain .

What I've tried:
I wrote an apk to change the permissions of the /sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness file to keep them off. Despite the program working , permissions allow the file be edited, causing them to light up.

What i need help on:
I downloaded my dev's kernel using git and I want to edit the kernel myself to keep the button lights off during sleep . However kernel code is not my comfort zone .. so i need help .

Thanks everyone for helping and simply just reading !

Comment: What are the permissions on that file?

Answer (score 0):

1) Messing with code is a bad idea (especially if you lack skill and don't know C and UNIX).

2) what you are probably looking for is script that will run on startup (**initrc**) and there you need to set it and change permissions using **chmod** command.

Thus you need to Setup what you want (with echo command presumably) -> change permissions so file can not be rewritten (chmod) -> put two commands in initrc.

Kernel can be like any other configured using make menuconfig and then compiling it, in that case you just disable stuff that you don't like.

[OT] I may be off though, your (original) question (there was no question mark) did not make too much sense here and there. [Read this howto: **How To Ask Questions The Smart Way**](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) from Eric Steven Raymond. Thanks.

Comment: I already did all that . I cant change the permissions because every thing ive changed it to still allows the file to be edited . And i do know unix and C im just not familiar with what needs to be edited inside the kernel to achieve what i want . and as far as a questions ...

WHat do i edit in the android kernel to keep the front facing button LEDs off during standby?

Comment: Unix permission system (rwx) "just works" for years (decades) and thus I assume you are doing something wrong (even kernel components tend to care about it as they use VFS).
Post here permissions you set please.

Comment: Well i was told by a friend on xda that chown root would work but it tells me there is no such user or group . So i was like ok i should be able to use chmod and i chmod 0000 to give it all nothing not even read . and IT DOES NOT WORK . the lights still come on . like seriously i wouldnt be posting if my APK worked .</NL>I did fail to mention im trying to accomplish this while the device is is deep sleep . the dev of my kernel was shocked to see that they came on in deep sleep . as was i .

Comment: That is not surprising, when it can not read something, it usually falls back to default. Just set 1 for everybody.
If that does not work, Idk, perhaps hw sets some default settings. Try emulator of your device and run debugger.

Comment: Still doesnt work .. Why cant something just work ? lol . Like i thought this would be a full proof method but i guess the kernel overides the value of /sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness ? Now i noticed this "/sys/class/lesds/button-backlight/trigger" what exactly is that ? to me it sounds like a file which tells what is allowed to trigger those lights . but i cant edit it even using echo . and there is "sleep" inside the file . Is it really that complicated to edit the kernel ??

Comment: Well, kernel generally does not override permissions (it's more likely that it will crash with permission error instead). My guess Is that hardware sets some defaults instead, but to really find out get sdk and emulate+debug this behaviour. If this is kernel problem, you can also get daemons that check access to file (or nodes) and then trace these (and report bug).
If I were you, I would go this way.

Comment: How would i emulate the problem when the emulator has no hardware buttons that light up ... what i would really like is something that lets me see whats turning on the lights during sleep . is that what the daemons do ? im not too familiar with debugging since this is hardware related .

Comment: "If this is kernel problem, yo..." I wasn't talking about hw then.
You can check when files change using inotify command for example.
You can emulate your android device in special emulators or in native sdk (can't tell how, I'm no droid developer).
If you suspect kernel is @fault, you can get usermodelinux, qemu and do standard kernel debugging.

Comment: Okay thanks i was wondering if anyone knew exactly what caused that seeing as it happens only on my phone and not on others . i wonder if its ROM related too ..